# Filtering a Kendo Grid on a custom object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grouping, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid with a display template that is using a custom object. I've implemented IComparable to allow grouping and sorting, but I'm not sure what I need to do to get the filtering to work. As it is, when I click the Filter button for the column it has a blank dropdown instead of the usual 'Contains, starts with, equals' and such options that would normally show. I am using the **ToDataSourceResult** to manipulate the results.

The model:

```
public class LEAProgramMap
{
    public string entity_program { get; set; }
    [UIHint("ProgramEditor")]
    public ProgramDDL program_desc { get; set; }
}
```

The dropdown:

```
public class ProgramDDL : IComparable
{
    public short program_id { get; set; }
    public string entity_program { get; set; }
    public string program_desc { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ProgramDDL)
        {
            ProgramDDL rev2 = (ProgramDDL)obj;
            return program_desc.CompareTo(rev2.program_desc);
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a ProgramDDL");
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Datamart.Models.ViewModels.LEAProgramMap>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateProgramMap";
    var snapshot = Session["snapshot_id"] ?? Request.Params["snapshot_id"];
}

<h2>CreateProgramMap</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Programs")
.Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(p => p.entity_program).ClientTemplate("#=entity_program#");
        cols.Bound(p => p.program_desc).ClientTemplate("#=program_desc.program_desc#");
    })
.ToolBar(commands =>
    {
        commands.Save();
    })
.Editable(edit => edit.Enabled(true).Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.DataSource(ds => ds
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.entity_program);
                    model.Field(p => p.entity_program).Editable(false);

                })
    // Configure RU -->
                .Read(read => read.Action("Program_Read", "Draft").Data("additionalData"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Program_Update", "Draft").Data("additionalData"))
    //.ServerOperation(false)
                .Batch(true)
                .Events(events => events
                    //.Change("onChange")
                    .Error("onError")
                    )
                )
        // <-- Configure RU
        .Pageable(page => page.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 }).Enabled(true))
        .Groupable(group => group.Enabled(true))
        .Filterable(filter => filter.Enabled(true).Extra(true))
        .Sortable(sort => sort.Enabled(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).AllowUnsort(true))
        .Navigatable(nav => nav.Enabled(true))
        .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            )

<script>
function additionalData() {
    return {
        snapshot_id: "@snapshot"
    };
}

function onError(e, status) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "The following errors have occurred:\n";

        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if (value.errors) {
                message += value.errors.join("\n");
            }
        });

        alert(message);
    }
}

function onChange() {
    var grid = $("#Programs").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.dataSource.read();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Kendo UI doesn't support Class Composition / View Models containing complex objects, your View Models need to be completely flat to avoid unexpected behaviour. So your class should look like this.

```
public class LEAProgramMap
{
    public string entity_program { get; set; }
    public short program_id { get; set; }
    public string entity_program { get; set; }
    public string program_desc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so I can use my current View Models for everything but filtering? I'll have to add a feature request for that - it seems odd since I think if it were an important feature I could implement them all in a custom resolver. I'll probably just add a search outside the grid for now if the client deems it important enough then go back after release look at more elegant solutions.

Comment: When I first stumbled across the fact Kendo UI View Models have to be completely flat was when I was trying to apply sorting, it seems to be able to Model Bind Correctly so it can display data. When you try to do anything with the DataSourceResult (Filter, Sorting, Grouping etc) it seems to give unexpected results.

Comment: I was able to sort with complex classes in Kendo after implementing IComparable though. Grouping also works - maybe because I'm using a template?

Comment: Hmm that could be a few things, the most likely reason is that your Model is a IList and the grouping / sorting is done In Memory and doesn't need to be translated to SQL - i was working with IQueryable's

Comment: here's the response from Kendo's support team:

I am sorry to say that filtering on a complex object is not supported and you are not able to change the built-in filter menu which is automatically generated (ddl not filled with options when column is bound to complex object).
I would suggest you to create an external widget/input to filter the dataSource just like in [http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html](this demo) - the DropDownList is positioned in the ToolBar and you can for example put it somewhere else on the page or even in the ColumnHeader of the Grid columns.

Comment: @Elsimer I am having similar issues with complex objects. I see you mentioned that grouping is working for complex objects but it's not working for me. Can you please let me know how to make the grouping work?

Comment: @jonni I didn't do anything special to get the grouping to work - have you implemented IComparable?