# Kendo Grid edit popup complex model submitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I’m trying to use complex models with Kendo grid edit popup. When submitting ALResults object properties are always null. It works fine when I’m not using Kendo. Is there a problem with kendo complex model submitting?

```
public class InitialApplicantLevel2Model
    {
        public InitialApplicantLevel2Model()
        {

            alResultsModel = new ALResults();
        }

        public int InitialApplicantLevel2ID { get; set; }
        public string ApplicantName { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Ref No. required.")]
        public int? EnquiryID { get; set; }



        public ALResults alResultsModel { get; set; }




    }

public class ALResults
    {
        public int ResultsID { get; set; }
        public int InitialApplicantLevel2ID { get; set; }
        public string Stream { get; set; }
        public string Grading { get; set; }
        public string IndexNo { get; set; }
        public int? Year { get; set; }
        public int? Attempt { get; set; }
        public double? ZScore { get; set; }
        public string Medium { get; set; }
    }



@model SIMS.Models.StudentIntake.InitialApplicantLevel2Model 
<tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.Year)</td>
        <td>Index No: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.IndexNo)</td>
        <td>Medium: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.Medium)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stream: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.Stream)</td>
        <td>Attempt: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.Attempt)</td>
        <td>Zscore: </td>
        <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResultsModel.ZScore)

        </td>
    </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484916/filtering-a-kendo-grid-on-a-custom-object)

> Unfortunately Kendo UI doesn't support Class Composition / View Models
>   containing complex objects, your View Models need to be completely
>   flat to avoid unexpected behaviour.